# Adding a Label to a form from a thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I am working on a VB.Net project and I'm trying to add a label to my form from a thread that is running in the background (a necessary evil).

I have created the Global variable SmallTextLabel (Type: Label) and have assigned all of the properties I want to it.  I am now just trying to add it to my form using Me.Controls.Add(SmallTextLabel).  Every time I run this code it tells me that i must invoke the control.  I scream at the screen that that's what I'm trying to do, but does it listen?!

Anyway, I have scoured the internet for the past 4 hours and have not managed to resolve this, so please... can anyone out there shine some light on this for me?

This is the code that I'm currently calling with AddSmallLabelControl(SmallTextLabel)

**Amended example**

```
Private Delegate Sub AddSmallLabelControlHandler(ByVal test As Label)
Private Sub AddSmallLabelControl(ByVal test As Label)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New AddSmallLabelControlHandler(AddressOf AddSmallLabelControl)
        Me.Invoke(d, test)
    Else
        Me.Controls.Add(test)
        test.BringToFront()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowScanConfirmationLabel()
    Dim SmallTextLabel As New Label
    Dim TahomaSmall As New Font("Tahoma", 20, FontStyle.Bold)

    With SmallTextLabel
        .Height = 40
        .Width = 312
        .Location = New Point(3, 121)
        .BackColor = Color.Green
        .Text = "Testing"
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
        .Font = TahomaSmall
    End With

    End With
    Call AddSmallLabelControl(SmallTextLabel)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MakeLabelsVisibleHandler As New ThreadStart(AddressOf MakeLabelsVisible)
    Dim timerThread As New Thread(MakeLabelsVisibleHandler)
    timerThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub MakeLabelsVisible()
    ShowScanConfirmationLabel()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hold on. In what thread do you initialize the Label? (Where do you actually set `SmallTextLabel = New Label()`), Also if you check `Me.SmallTextLabel.InvokeRequired` then you should invoke `SmallTextlabel.Invoke(...)` but when you define and initialize the laben in the seperate thread you might want to check `Me.InvokeRequired` instead...

Comment: I am currently initializing the label in the calling thread.Dim SmallTextLabel As New Label

Comment: If Not Me.SmallTextLabel.InvokeRequired Then Throw New Exception("You are doing it wrong, try using Me instead")

Comment: Have added an answer in that regard :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have detected a little but grave inconsitancy in your code, that could may the effect that you actually don't run the invoke...

Assuming you initialize the Label in your working thread, then checking `Me.SmallLabel.InvokeRequired` will return False since it has been created on the same thread. Thus your procedure never actually will call the `Me.Invoke(...)`

When you try to access the Controls of the Form that has been created on another thread, you should check whether that Form requires an Invoke. In your case: `Me.InvokeRequired`

Try this Code instead:

```
Private Delegate Sub AddSmallLabelControlHandler(ByVal test As Label)
Private Sub AddSmallLabelControl(ByVal test As Label)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New AddSmallLabelControlHandler(AddressOf AddSmallLabelControl)
        Me.Invoke(d, test)
    Else
        Me.Controls.Add(test)
        ' If you need .BringToFront use it here:
        test.BringToFront()
        ' But like this it is called every time you add a label of course.
    End If
End Sub
```

.

**Edit:** 
Concerning `.NET CF`

So it seems `Invoke` *behaves* in some unique ways on the Compact Framework. Namely it expects to invoke an `EventHandler` and **nothing else**.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446540.aspx)

In that case we have to refactor our code:

First of all since we have to use `EventHandler`, we need to use it's signature which is `EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)`

So when we need to send a fresh `Label` to the target procedure, a simple solution would be to put it in `sender` and cast it afterwards.

But the prudent way to do is to implement your own `EventArgs` class containing one `Control` and cast that one.

So here the VB variant of sample code showing how to invoke controls on the CF

```
' Start the worker thread
Private Sub InitWorker()
    Dim trdWorker As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf WorkerThread))
    trdWorker.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub WorkerThread()
    Dim testLabel As New Label() With {
        .Name = "TestLabel",
        .Text = "Test Label",
        .Location = New Point(5, 30)
    }
    ' Create your EventArgs containing the control you wish to add
    Dim e As New AddControlEventArgs(testLabel)

    ' Create EventHandler
    Dim ehnd As New EventHandler(AddressOf AddControl)

    ' Invoke EventHandler with EventArgs (don't need sender as of now)
    Me.Invoke(ehnd, Nothing, e)
End Sub

' Define your custom EventArgs to hold one Control
Public Class AddControlEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
    Public Sub New(p_control As Control)
        m_control = p_control
    End Sub
    Private m_control As Control
    Public ReadOnly Property Control As Control
        Get
            Return m_control
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Private Sub AddControl(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Cast EventArgs to your custom EventArgs
    Dim ec As AddControlEventArgs = DirectCast(e, AddControlEventArgs)
    Me.Controls.Add(ec.Control)

    ' Still, do you need this?
    ec.Control.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Some final notes:

- My solution differs from the one found at the MSDN source in one fundamental way.
  The MSDN solution stores the *message* it want's to invoke on a *neutral* field in the class, I create own EventArgs that hold the *message* (in our case a `Control`)
- I don't have the CF environment installed, so i could not Test the solution **on** a CF environment. It would be great to have some *feedback*, whether this actually solved the issue
- You should tag your post with `compact-framework`, as solutions on the CF can be fundamentally different from *normal* solutions (proved by this predicament)

Comment: If you add an explanation describing what was wrong with Jason's code and how and why your code fixes it, I would gladly upvote your answer.

Comment: Edited post. Do you think that explanation is sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, but this still hasn't gotten me out of the woods unfortunately.  Every time I run the code, the     Me.Invoke(d, test) is bringing up the message Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread. :(

Comment: Yes.  Nice answer!  Just a helpful hint: if you want to gain reputation around here, I've found that getting up-votes is more about having a good and thorough answer than it is about just being right.

Comment: Ok, i failed to reproduce your error... you'll have to post more code

Comment: @MrPaulch I've added as much code as I can relating to this issue.  I hope there's something obvious I've done wrong as this is just baffling me.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you call `.BringToFront` later in your working Thread. That needs to be invoked aswell. Try it without those lines. If you absolutly need `.BringToFront`, you could put it in the `AddSmallLabelControl` as seen in my code shortly.

Comment: @MrPaulch Thanks for your time on this question.  I've tried that, and my code is still falling over in exactly the same place, for exactly the same reason. :(  Do you have any other ideas on this issue?

Comment: Have you actually updated the InvokeRequired check as I have proposed in my answer?

Comment: @MrPaulch Yes Sorry.  I forgot to amend the example on the forum.  Still no success with the amendment in place. :(

Comment: I took the code and implemented it. No errors. What Framwork Version do you use?

Comment: @MrPaulch Unfortunately, I'm using Compact Framework 3.5 for a scanner terminal.  I'm going to bet that the reason this isn't working is that it's yet another case of functionality missing from Compact Framework (finding this is happening more and more with this project).  I might have to take this code over into a new project and see if I get the same result before I head down the route of trying to find another way around the issue. :(  ...unless you have any experience of Compact Framework?

Comment: Well a google search for `Invoking Controls in Compact Framework` yields a few results. First of all it is made apparent that Invoke is implemented on the `Control` Class directly instead of the `ISynchronizeInvoke` Interface in `.NET CF` and behaves in slightly different ways. Some are claiming that as I pointed out in my first comment to your Q you'll have to invoke your control instead of your Form (seems suspicious though), others are claiming you have to use `EventHandler` as your delegate when invoking controls. Some more research is prudent i think.

Answer (score 0):

By moving the creation of the label inside the invocation, the code runs without issue.  Thank you to @MrPaulch for all of his help on this issue.  Will 1up your last comment.

```
Private Delegate Sub AddSmallLabelControlHandler(ByVal test As String)
Private Sub AddSmallLabelControl(ByVal test As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New AddSmallLabelControlHandler(AddressOf AddSmallLabelControl)
        Me.Invoke(d, test)
    Else
        Dim SmallTextLabel As New Label
        Dim TahomaSmall As New Font("Tahoma", 20, FontStyle.Bold)

        With SmallTextLabel
            .Height = 40
            .Width = 312
            .Location = New Point(3, 121)
            .BackColor = Color.Green
            .Text = test
            .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
            .Font = TahomaSmall
        End With            
        Me.Controls.Add(SmallTextLabel)
        test.BringToFront()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MakeLabelsVisibleHandler As New ThreadStart(AddressOf MakeLabelsVisible)
    Dim timerThread As New Thread(MakeLabelsVisibleHandler)
    timerThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub MakeLabelsVisible()
    Call AddSmallLabelControl("This now works")
End Sub
```